# Oracle, JDBI @SqlBatch - Get all rows touched by INSERT

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, jdbi

I have an Oracle 12c database. There's a table named Artifacts in it. The table looks like this:

```
ID | BONETYPE | AGE
```

`ID` is a `NUMBER(12,0)` GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY so the database assigns those when artifacts are inserted. `BONETYPE` & `AGE` are just strings. There's a unique constraint over `BONETYPE` & `AGE`.

I have a database query to insert missing records that looks like this:

```
INSERT /*+ IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX(Artifacts, U_ARTIFACTS) */
INTO Artifacts ("BONETYPE", "AGE")
VALUES ('dinosaur', '800000');
```

The weird hint `IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX`, is because some of these artifacts may already have been inserted.

This database query is actually issued through a JDBI query:

```
@SqlBatch("INSERT /*+ IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX(Artifacts, U_ARTIFACTS) */\n" +
          "INTO Artifacts ( \"BONETYPE\", \"AGE\" )\n" +
          "VALUES ( :BoneType, :Age )")
@GetGeneratedKeys(columnName = "ID", value = OracleGeneratedKeyMapper.class)
int[] putArtifacts(@Bind("BoneType") List<String> boneTypes, @Bind("Age") List<String> ages);
```

It's a `@SqlBatch` for performance reasons.

The problem I have now is that I want to know the `IDs` of all the affected rows, including the ones that were ignored due to `IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX` hint. How do I do that?

`@GetGeneratedKeys` only gets me the `IDs` of the rows of the missing records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot do this. You have to write a stored procedure to get all the `IDs`